# Перегрузка оператора "+" в шаблоне

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу правильно перегрузить оператор сложения в шаблоне класса. Может кто показать мне мою ошибку? Тип данных массива в шаблоне может быть char,int, float, double. Должно поддерживаться сложение разных типов данных (т.е. если первый объект с параметром int, а второй - с параметром double, то метод должен возвращать объект с параметром double).

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    T *data;
    size_t size;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(size_t size);
    ~Vector();
    size_t getSize();
    void SetAll();
    void ClearAll();
    void SetVectorSize(size_t);
    T operator [](int);
    template< typename U >
    Vector & operator+(Vector <U> &B);
};
```

cpp файл:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Vector.h"
#include <typeinfo.h>
#include <iostream>
...
...
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
inline Vector & Vector<T>::operator+(Vector<U>& B)
{
    if (sizeof(this->data[0]) > sizeof(B.data[0]))
    {
        Vector <T> obj;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector <U> obj;
    }
    obj.data[0] = 1;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Пожалуйста, форматируйте код как код. У вас же все угловые скобки оказались съедены - не понять что к чему.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я верно понял, что вы хотите, то решение примерно такое -

```
template<typename U>
Vector<common_type_t<T,U>> operator+(const Vector<U>&) const
{
    Vector<std::common_type_t<T,U>> x;
    // складываете, как вам надо .......
    return x;
}
```

Код

```
Vector<int> a;
Vector<double> b;
auto c = a+b;
cout << typeid(c).name() << endl;
```

даст `Vector<double>`.

И еще - вы должны объявить этот оператор как возвращающий вектор нового типа, а не ссылку - иначе вы по сути вынуждены возвращать ссылку на свой объект, а его тип предопределен.

**Update** В принципе, можно как-то так - но, как мне кажется, это будет совсем не так красиво:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator+(const Vector<U>&A) const
{
    Vector<decltype(T(0)+U(0))> x;
    return x;
}
```

Т.е. даем компилятору самому решить, какой тип имеет сумма, и этот тип используем для типа возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Harry. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу задать длину вектора объекта х в методе(в обоих вариантах). Она все равно остается 0.

Comment: @rankery Простите, не очень понял. Ну пишете `Vector<std::common_type_t<T,U>> x(needed_size);` и все. Отрабатывает конструктор с указанием размера. Или я неверно понял, что вас интересует?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Harry. Решил не создавать новую тему для вопроса, а ограничиться комментарием. Пришлось перегружать операцию присваивания, но при присваивание не вызывает то, что я перегружал. Вот прототип: `template<typename U> Vector <T> & operator =(const Vector <U>& A);` . Определение VS создает сам. Не могли бы Вы показать мне мою ошибку?

Comment: @rankery Т.е. вы даете только объявление, но тела функции у вас нет? Непонятно, что там вообще у вас. Вы бы не могли где-то выложить свой код, потому что по вашему вопросу, откровенно говоря, непонятно, о чем идет речь.

Comment: [ссылка на код](http://vpaste.net/Vr4p4). Я там разделил .cpp и .h файлы. Сама перегрузка находится в самом низу

Comment: @rankery http://vpaste.net/Ybvf7 См. там комментарии, отмеченные как `// Harry`. Оно не то чтобы не вызывает, оно просто не компилируется. Я сделал, чтобы компилировалось, но - на всякий случай - в самой логике не копался, это ваше :)

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так (`C++11`):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class Enable = void>
class Vector;

template <typename T>
class Vector<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
{
    T *data;
    size_t size;

public:
    Vector(){};
    Vector(size_t _size) : size(_size){}
    ~Vector(){}
    size_t getSize();
    void SetAll();
    void ClearAll();
    void SetVectorSize(size_t);
    T operator [](int);
    Vector<T> operator+ (Vector<T>& B)
    {
        return Vector<T>(size + B.size);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector<int> a;
    Vector<int> b;
    a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы показали, как ограничиться целочисленными элементами и с плавающей точкой? Но я так понял, что главная проблема - приведение при суммировании, чтоб было выполнено верное приведение при суммировании векторов с разными типами.

Comment: @Harry Ну, возможно, я неправильно понял вопрос, но, вообще, тогда автору стоило бы сформулировать его куда точнее.